# WPF - Cannot convert text from TextBox to Double

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am having trouble converting the text from a TextBox to Double. In Win Forms it was fairy simple to convert it using the ToDouble() method, however now in WPF I am having issues with this.

First of all in the Main Window I have an int declared to help Id-ing other controls, this int is incremented only when pressing a button in order to add extra controls. Also I have a double[] declared to pass information from textboxes.

This is the int and double declaration:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int i = 0;
        double[] Fi;
```

Now in the button pressed method I am trying to pass the information to the array from the textbox:

```
Fi[i] = double.Parse(textBox15.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("" + Fi[i]);
```

This is the error message I get when debugging the code:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WpfApplication2.exe
```

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The textbox is not null since I am inputing value to it from the keyboard, in this stage i = 0. Any advise on this matter? It is the 3rd attempt to convert, I have also user so far:

```
Fi[i] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox15.Text);
```

also giving the same error.

Comment: Step through it with the debugger and see what is or isn't null. My guess? Fi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Init the Fi array first:

```
double [] Fi = new double [3];
```

And have a look at this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it did the trick ! So I take it I cannot just create an array without knowing how many elements it will have ? That was what I was trying to do.

Comment: Take a look at `List<T>`

Comment: Thank you Charles, I went through Lists and it was even better to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new array... for example:

```
double[] fi = new double[10];
```